# PHP ZipArchive::close returns false

Tags: php, zip, docx, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to change some docx variables from PHP. But on save step always got false.

I tried to 777 permissions to directory, php-zip extension, "ext-zip": "*" in composer.json.

My code:

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();

        $wordDoc = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../file.docx';
        $fileToModify = 'word/document.xml';

        if ($zip->open($wordDoc, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
            $oldContents = $zip->getFromName($fileToModify);

            $newContents = str_replace(' MERGEFIELD __FIRSTNAME__ ', 'NEWNAME', $oldContents);

            $zip->deleteName($fileToModify);

            $zip->addFromString($fileToModify, $newContents);

            if ($zip->close()) {
                echo "Done.";
            }
            else {
                echo 'fail';exit();
            }
        }
```

php -m zip enabled:

```
zip,
zlib
```

php --ini zip enabled:

```
/etc/php7/conf.d/00_zip.ini,
```

I expect overwrite old file and get new with new values but always got false on `$zip->close();`

Comment: You said you tried 777 permission on directory. Did you also do 666 on file?

Comment: @apokryfos, same result

Comment: Try doing `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in case there's any warning that's being thrown

Comment: @apokryfos, nothing. $zip->getStatusString(); says "No error"; All of methods returns true.

Comment: There's a few reasons it can legitimately return false, like if the zip is empty etc, have you checked that the files you're adding actually exist?

Comment: @naththedeveloper, yes. I solved the problem. Cant work with original file. Before process needs to create a copy

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Before working needs to create a copy of origin file.

```
$original = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../file.docx';
if (copy($original, $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../temp/newFile.docx')) {
      $tempFile = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../temp/newFile.docx';
}
```